# Table View cell width is smaller than Table View Width

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, scaling

I am making a side bar menu which slides from left! It is set with animation. In the beginning the scale of side bar menu (which is table view controller) is 0.7, after it becomes visible the scale increases to 1.0. The problem is when the scale increases the width of the cell stays the same as it was in the scale of 0.7. However, the width of tableViewController increases. I don't understand why the width of cell doesn't increase together with UITableViewContoller width?

```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("sideBarCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = arrayMenu[indexPath.row]


    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    cell.textLabel?.font =  UIFont(name: "Avenir-Book", size: 25)

    cell.textLabel?.sizeToFit()
    cell.updateConstraints()
    return cell
}
```

Comment: you are creating the cells layout via code or xib?

Comment: it is not custom cell. Yes, I am creating it with code. I will add code above